# Don't found a class php imported with composer

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, respect-validation

in my project I have imported by composer `respect/validator`. Now, I have a file (login.php) in a subfolder of subfolder where I need it.
The Respect/Validation's documentation says write:

`<?php
 use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;`

obviously I must require my `vendor/autoload.php` (autogenerate Composer's file), I do it in index.php of my project in the root. Well, it work for every packages (Slim, twig...) but not for Respect/Validation, I try also with other package into my login.php but it's the same.

the error is: `Fatal error: Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found`

so, i try also to require here the autoload.php and the results:

`Warning: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')`

I think that the problem is with autoload.php or with the path. Because I should not need the autoload in login.php or however when I require it, it should not change the error...

Comment: Have you set your `include_path` (using `set_include_path()`) so that your file can find `vendor/autoload.php` and that the autoloader can find the other classes? Do you need to register the autoloader after including `vendor/autoload.php` or is just including it enough?

Comment: I including vendor/autoload.php in the root page of project. For example, for my package of Mongo DB it work correctly.
Then, when I write only use Respect\Validation\Validator as v; it doesn't give me problems, it don't work when i try to operate with v o with the istance...

I try now to use set_include_path() in my login.php but it desn't work!